# Advertisement banner for iPhone application

Tags: iphone, ios6, ads

I want to integrate advertisement in my iPhone application. Client will provide API for it. Can I use iAdd for this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

If your client will provide an api to show an ad banner then it would be implemented like a custom ad banner. All other ad services show and represent the specific ad services . They showcase their own ads, while your client wants to his own from what I infer. So I suggest call the API in a custom made view and proceed.

Comment: I have seen web side. There is add in box form. But in iPhone there we have to show in banner. Then how it will manage UI scaling?